# Configure AVAssetCache to store AVURLAsset

Tags: avplayer, avurlasset

I'm trying to access property assetCache from AVURLAsset object, but it's always nil.

Documentation provides next information:

```
/*!
  @property assetCache
  @abstract Provides access to an instance of AVAssetCache to use for 
  inspection of locally cached media data. Will be nil if an asset has 
  not been configured to store or access media data from disk.
*/
@property (nonatomic, readonly, nullable) AVAssetCache *assetCache NS_AVAILABLE(10_12, 10_0);
```

So, how can I configure AVURLAsset to make it possible to store or access media data from disk?